# ReactJS: onClick change element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started learning React and have a question.

I want to do the following:

If a user clicks on a paragraph I want to change the element to an input field that has the contents of the paragraph prefilled. 
(The end goal is direct editing if the user has certain privileges)

I'm come this far but am totally at a loss.

```
var AppHeader = React.createClass({
    editSlogan : function(){
        return (
            <input type="text" value={this.props.slogan} onChange={this.saveEdit}/>
         )
    },
    saveEdit : function(){
        // ajax to server
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <header>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                            <p onClick={this.editSlogan}>{this.props.slogan}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
});
```

How can I override the render from the `editSlogan` function?

Comment: Use "contenteditable="true" inside div.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If I understand your questions correctly, you want to render a different element in case of an "onClick" event.

This is a great use case for react states.

Take the following example

```
React.createClass({ 
    getInitialState : function() {
       return { showMe : false };
    },
    onClick : function() {
       this.setState({ showMe : true} );
    },
    render : function() {
        if(this.state.showMe) { 
            return (<div> one div </div>);
        } else { 
            return (<a onClick={this.onClick}> press me </a>);
        } 
    }
})
```

This will change the components state, and makes React render the div instead of the a-tag. When a components state is altered(using the setState method), React calculates if it needs to rerender itself, and in that case, which parts of the component it needs to rerender.

More about states
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

Comment: This is perfect! I feel so stupid but I've learned a lot! Thank you so much!

Comment: How about inside return ?

Comment: What if I have a list of slogans with "edit" button next to each one? And I can edit each slogan one by one clicking their edit buttons. Seems like in this situation to make a condition for each line would not be a good way.

Comment: the above should be updated to cover React 16 and ES6 syntax

Comment: what if i had multiple elements , like `<td>` in table , i can't just set state to each element ?

Comment: @sasharomanov you have to create a Children element to call from   Parent so you can map it and use your props

Answer (score 5):

You can solve it a little bit more clear way:

```js
class EditableLabel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: props.value,
            editing: false
        };
        this.initEditor();
        this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
        this.save = this.save.bind(this);
    }

    initEditor() {
        this.editor = <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.text} onKeyPress={(event) => {
            const key = event.which || event.keyCode;
            if (key === 13) { //enter key
                this.save(event.target.value)
            }
        }} autoFocus={true}/>;
    }

    edit() {
        this.setState({
            text: this.state.text,
            editing: true
        })
    };

    save(value) {
        this.setState({
            text: value,
            editing: false
        })
    };

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.initEditor();
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.editing ?
            this.editor
            : <p onClick={this.edit}>{this.state.text}</p>
    }
}

//and use it like <EditableLabel value={"any external value"}/>;
```